# Pandas function taking too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract the top level URLs and ignore the paths. I am using the code below:

```
for row in Mexico['Page URL']:
    parsed_uri = urlparse( 'http://www.one.com.mx/furl/Conteúdo Raiz/Meu' )
    Mexico['SubDomain'] = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
```

This script has been running for the past hour. When I ran it, it gave the following warning:

```
/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could advise on a quicker way, perhaps pointers on the method the 'warning' suggests

Comment: For a start move the `urlparse` call outside the loop. It does the same thing each time. You dont even use `row` in your loop, so why have the loop? Did you enter your code wrong?

Comment: Thanks for assisting. The URLs are different for the dataframe. If I move this out of the loop how would I accmodate for this?

Comment: This is probably part of my isse. I am trying to loop throught the data frame and copy the domain/sub domain, ignoring the path

Comment: Do all your urls begin with `http://`?

Comment: They begin  with https://

Comment: Since it sounds like `Mexico` is very long, it might be hard to check by hand. So to be on the safe side, what does `Mexico['Page URL'].str.startswith('https://').all()` return?

Comment: False..but ideally would like to exlude the ones that dont start with https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling a Python function once for each row of a Series can be very slow if the Series is very long. The key to speeding this up is replacing the multiple function calls with (ideally) one vectorized function call.

When using Pandas, that means rewriting the Python function (e.g. `urlparse`) in terms of [vectorized string functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#working-with-text-data).

Since `urlparse` is a [fairly complicated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/parse.py#L359) function, rewriting `urlparse` would be pretty hard. However, in your case we have the advantage of knowing that all the urls that we care about begin with `https://` or `http://`. So we don't need `urlparse` in its full-blow generality. We can perhaps make do with a much simpler rule: *The netloc is whatever characters follow `https://` or `http://` until the end of the string or the next `/`, whichever comes first*.
If that is true, then

```
Mexico['Page URL'].str.extract('(https?://[^/]+)', expand=False)
```

can extract all the netlocs from the entire Series `Mexico['Page URL']` without looping and without multiple `urlparse` function calls. This will be much faster when `len(Mexico)` is big.

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

Mexico = pd.DataFrame({'Page URL':['http://www.one.com.mx/furl/Conteúdo Raiz/Meu',
                                   'https://www.one.com.mx/furl/Conteúdo Raiz/Meu']})

Mexico['SubDomain'] = Mexico['Page URL'].str.extract('(https?://[^/]+)', expand=False)
print(Mexico)
```

yields

```
                                        Page URL               SubDomain
0   http://www.one.com.mx/furl/Conteúdo Raiz/Meu   http://www.one.com.mx
1  https://www.one.com.mx/furl/Conteúdo Raiz/Meu  https://www.one.com.mx
```

Comment: Can i add a condtion to catch both http AND https?

Comment: Sure. In that case, the [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) would be `https?://[^/]+`. I've modified the code above to show what I mean.